# Fixed or random effect in linear mixed effect

Tags: r, mixed-model, linear-model

Let say I've a dataframe as :

```
image_id image_group group x y nn
```

I've 20 images defined by image_id ; each image belongs to a group G1 or G2 defined in the image_group column.
Eeach image is a list of points from different groups (e.g. A, B and C) defined by their coordinates x and y. nn represents the number of neighbour of the point in a predefined radius e.g. r=100.

My goal is to compare two groups of points by their minimal distances. As an example A vs B : I compute for each point of A : the distance to all points of B and report the minimal distance. Thus if I've 100 A points it will report 100 distances.

Using these distances I want to compare group G1 vs G2 and see if A vs B distances are different.

My idea was to use a linear mixed model and use nn as a covariate but not sure if it should be used as fixed or random effect.

In R (for the example I generate a dist column to simulate the distance between points. Here group G1 has a lower number of neihgbour compared to G2.

```
require(lme4)
require(lmerTest)

set.seed(123)
dat <- 
  data.frame(
    image_id = c(rep(1:5,1000),rep(6:10,1000)),
    image_group = c(rep("G1",1000),rep("G2",1000)),
    dist = rnorm(2000,mean=50,sd=10),
    nn = c( round(rnorm(1000,mean = 20,sd=5)),round(rnorm(1000,mean=30,sd=5))))


# version without using nn as covariate
mixed.lmer <- lmer(dist ~  image_group + (1|image_id), data = dat)

# version with nn as random effect
mixed.lmer2 <- lmer(dist ~  image_group + (1|image_id) + (1|nn), data = dat)

# version with nn as fixed effect
mixed.lmer3 <- lmer(dist ~  image_group + nn + (1|image_id) , data = dat)

anova(mixed.lmer)
anova(mixed.lmer2)
anova(mixed.lmer3)
```

Hereby the results

```
> anova(mixed.lmer)
Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
            Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF DenDF F value Pr(>F)
image_group 173.41  173.41     1  9998   1.733 0.1881

> anova(mixed.lmer2)
Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
            Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF  DenDF F value Pr(>F)
image_group 90.472  90.472     1 1793.8  0.9183 0.3381

> anova(mixed.lmer3)
Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
            Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF DenDF F value  Pr(>F)  
image_group 385.83  385.83     1  9997  3.8563 0.04959 *
nn          213.12  213.12     1  9997  2.1300 0.14447  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Which one will be the most suitable ? In this simulated example, results can be really different depending on the model. As number of neighbours can obviously bias the minimal distance calculation (More points in the vicinity -> more chance to have a point of group B close )

Thank you the help and comments

**EDIT**

Following @Doctor Milt advice I used a gam

Here's the plot of the model

```
model4 <- gam(dmin ~  image_group + s(nn) + s(image_id, bs = "re"), data = dat)
plot(model4)
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't `nn` a numeric variable? In `mixed.lmer2` you're treating it as a categorical variable, which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Your argument about the number of neighbours having an effect on the minimal distance is sensible, and I can totally believe that the relationship between the two is not linear (which is the assumption in `mixed.lmer3`), so maybe try a spline?

Comment: @DoctorMilt indeed it's not categorical. And indeed thinking about it has no sense to use it as a random effect then. So model 2 should be thrown away. Thanks for the comment

Comment: Regarding the spline. Which package will you use. Sorry I'm not an expert in modelling :/

Comment: No problem! I've added a proper answer.

Comment: As image_group is a binary outcome, is a glmer a good idea instead of a lmer. Thus 
`m <- glmer(image_group ~ dmin + nn + (1 | image_id), data = dat, family = binomial, control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"), nAGQ = 0)`  or maybe add a interaction between nn and dmin as : `m <- glmer(image_group ~ dmin + nn + dmin * nn + (1 | image_id), data = dat, family = binomial, control = glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa"), nAGQ = 0)`  . Then I can extract dmin estimate and p-value with `broom::tidy()` . What do you think @DoctorMilt ? Thank you

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Keep in mind that you can fit a GAM with binary outcomes. Syntax would be `gam(image_group ~  dmin + s(nn) + s(image_id, bs = "re") , data = dat, family = binomial)`

Answer (score 1):

Deciding whether to include a covariate using fixed or random effects is relevant when the variable is categorical. In this situation, `nn` is numeric (an integer).

For example, here are the estimates of the random effects and their standard errors from your second model (`mixed.lmer2`).
[image]
Clearly not what we want!

As I mentioned in my comment, your argument about the number of neighbours having an effect on the minimal distance is sensible, though the relationship between the two might be nonlinear. You could use the **mgcv** package to fit a GAM where you include `nn` as a spline.

**mgcv** allows you to add random effects, so you could keep `image_id` in there. The syntax would be something like

```
library(mgcv)
model4 <- gam(dist ~  image_group + s(nn) + s(image_id, bs = "re") , data = dat)
```

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. Regarding the relationship between distance and number of neighbours, what will be the best way to test it ? gam and lmer gave very different results on the test dataset I gave in example. I also tested in my real dataset and results are also quiet different. Thanks

Comment: Did you try plotting this model? What does the spline look like?

Comment: I edited my question to add the plot

Comment: Looking at the plot on the left (`s(nn)` vs. `nn`), I'm not surprised you get very different results. In `mixed.lmer3` you're assuming that the relationship between the outcome and `nn` is linear, but there's clear evidence of nonlinearity. Once `nn` exceeds 250 or so, it looks flat to me.

Comment: ok thus I should go for the gam method then I guess ?

Comment: Yes, I think it makes more sense.